# Make a .net WebForm dynamic without autopostback

Tags: c#, .net, webforms, autopostback

Here's my issue, I'm using visual studios 2010 and I'm trying to create a form to fill then send it. This form requires a fileupload and some informations. The problem is that when I want to show/hide some pannel or textbox I can't do it dynamicly and I have to use autopost back which unselect the file selected in the fileupload control :

```
   protected void CB_image_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CB_image.Checked)
        {
            PanelImage.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            PanelImage.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

This is an exemple of code i'd like to pull out without using autopostback property on my CB_image (CB = checkbox). Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239397/asp-net-keep-fileupload-after-postback

Comment: use ajax, put upload file in updatepanel.

Comment: Trying this right now, I'll let you know the result

Comment: @ShoaibShaikh  Edit : nevermind, it works fine, thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. Something has to trigger a postback so the code on the server-side can check whether the checkbox is checked or not, and act according to it.

You can use a javascript timer that initiates a postback and work that way, I wouldn't do that though.

btw,

```
   protected void CB_image_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PanelImage.Visible = CB_image.Checked;
    }
```

looks much cleaner!

Comment: Oh, thanks for the answer, if there is no way to do it I guess I'll have to let it be that way.